# Can there be nothing after "return"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

```
def analyze_html(url, root_url):
    savepath = download_file(url)
    if savepath is None:
        return  # here
    if savepath in proc_files:
        return  # here
    proc_files[savepath] = True
    print("analyze_html", url)
    html = open(savepath, "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
    links = enum_links(html, url)
    for link_url in links:
        if link_url.find(root_url) != 0:
            if not re.search(r".css$", link_url):
                continue 
        if re.search(r".(html|htm)$", link_url):
            analyze_html(link_url, root_url)
            continue
        download_file(link_url)
```

Please refer to the if statements that I wrapped with double-asterisks.
I thought there always must be somthing after "return" for taht to be returned.
What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

`return` on its own is the same as `return None`

See the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement).

Comment: Double that. You can also use it to terminate a function early